# Node.js run app from terminal all work fine but when app start by npm "start" script it load only html without all static files in public folder

Tags: node.js, express, npm-scripts, static-files, npm-start

I have simple web site that use node.js and express.js
When I start my app.js file from terminal with command "node app.js" or "nodemon app.js" it work fine. It loads all my static file like css and images from public folder.
But when I run npm start script it run but don't load my static files like images and css files, only html file without applying my css classes and not displaying images.
I need to solve this issue because I want to deploy my website to heroku but heroku to run app uses start script from package.json

Part of my html document where I link .css file and use images

```html
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

      <!-- Load Google Fonts -->
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700&family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- Load styles.css file -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">

      <title>Online Learning</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <header class="section-header">
            <div class="base-container header-container top-nav" id="myTopNav">
               <div class="logo">
                  <img src="/images/polygon.png" alt="polygon" class="polygon">
                  <img src="/images/skilline.png" alt="brand-name" class="brand-name">
               </div>
```

and my app.js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    let date = new Date(Date.now());
    let serverStartTime = date.getDate() + "." + date.getMonth() + "." + date.getFullYear() + "  " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
    console.log("Server was start/restart on port 3000: " + serverStartTime);
});
```

my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "online-learning-landing-page",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "node src/app.js",
    "start": "npm run dev"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/grigore994/Online-Learning-Landing-Page.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/grigore994/Online-Learning-Landing-Page/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/grigore994/Online-Learning-Landing-Page#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

and my project structure

[image]

result when I run "node app.js" from terminal
[image]

and result when I run npm start script

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dont put app.js inside public, This is dangerous and not recommended.
Move it one directory above, the same level of your package.json

Then change this line to     "dev": "node app.js",

Comment: app.js file isn't in public folder, folder public and app.js is in src folder. But I moved public folder one directory above(outside src folder) and issue disappeared.